# Can't select Continental Portugal when using OSMNX

Tags: python, data-science, osmnx

The issue I am having is the following: Portugal is a country next to Spain and it also has some islands. I want to select only Continental Portugal, what I mean by this is just the part of Portugal next to Spain and not include the islands.

Can you help me please?

Thank you for the attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have probably done to download your data from [OpenStreetMap](https://geoffboeing.com/publications/osmnx-complex-street-networks/) using [OSMNX](https://geoffboeing.com/publications/osmnx-complex-street-networks/) is this:

```
import osmnx as ox
import geopandas as gpd
region = {'country':'Portugal'}
gdf = ox.gdf_from_place(region)
fig, ax = ox.plot_shape(gdf, figsize=(7,7))
```

which results in:

[image: Portugal]

namely, the continental part of Portugal + its islands, the [Azores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azores).

As the continental part is the largest, you can filter the other out using [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html) or [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/) for example.

But first, let's explore the data, here's `gdf`:

[image: Initial gdf content]

It's a multi-polygon. So, we need to explode it, e.g. according to [this](https://gist.github.com/mhweber/cf36bb4e09df9deee5eb54dc6be74d26#gistcomment-2743704):

```
exploded_gdf = gdf.explode()
```

I am using GeoPandas version `'0.7.0'`, this may not work with older versions.

Let's explore this new geometry:

[image: Exploded geometry]

As the continental part is probably the largest, you can compute and sort them by their area:

```
exploded_gdf['area'] = exploded_gdf.area
exploded_gdf.sort_values(by='area', inplace=True)
exploded_gdf
```

[image: Portugal areas]

And finally take the largest, here the last one, hence the index `-1`:

```
# Extract the shapely underlying geometry:
continental_part = exploded_gdf.iloc[-1]['geometry']
```

[image: Continental part]

Comment: Hint: for geographical questions, you would probably have higher chances of having answers on [GIS.SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Oh wow, I didi not know of the exploded command. Thank you very much !

Comment: I have another question, I want to plot all the the rodes and nodes existing in continental_par, however I don't know how to. Can you help me?